# Babel-node cannot compile js under node_modules, how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-node

I've struggled for this question for a long time, i've tried all possible solutions by google, but it still didn't work.
Here, i set an brief example to describe the problem.  Assume we created the structure:

```
test
|  
|____ test1.js
|
|____ node_modules
|     |
|     |____ test2.js
|     |
|     |____ [babel modules...]
|  
|____ .babelrc
|  
|____ package.json
```

test1.js / test2.js:

```
console.log({
  ...{a: 123}
})
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

**Test in normal situation**

```
node_modules/.bin/babel-node test1.js
```

Result:

```
{ a: 123 }
```

**Test in node_modules situation**

```
node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/test2.js
```

Result:

```
...{a: 123}
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is not using/finding the presets anymore, try copying .babelrc to node_modules.

Comment: Yes or no. In the example case, it works, but in other situations,like: `babel-node  node_modules/oneModule/main/index.js, it still doesn't work.  
However, i change the way by coping the files to compile to local to complete task.
Anyway, thanks a lot.